# How to scale the image along X and Y axis and crop to a specific height and width?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need to the stretch the images in X and Y directions but at the same time keep the target image size 300x300. I am using Open CV. Everytime I scale the image and then resize it, I lose the scaling and it looks the same as the image I fed it to scale. How do I accomplish this?

This is the code for scaling

```
def scale(infile,outfile,scx,scy):
    img = cv2.imread(infile,0)
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    #aspectRatio = width / height
    rows,cols = img.shape
    if scx > 1 or scy > 1:
        scimg = cv2.resize(img,None, fx = scx, fy = scy, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    else:
        scimg = cv2.resize(img,None, fx = scx, fy = scy, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    #cheight, cwidth = scimg.shape[:2]
    #area = cheight * cwidth
    #nheight = math.sqrt(area / aspectRatio)
    #nwidth = nheight * aspectRatio
    #cv2.resize(scimg,((int)(nwidth), (int)(nheight)), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    #top = (int) (0.2*rows)
    #bottom = (int) (0.2*rows)
    #left = (int) (0.2*cols)
    #right = (int) (0.2*cols);
    #cv2.copyMakeBorder(scimg,top,left,bottom,right,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=255)
    cv2.imwrite(outfile,scimg)
```

and I use the scales array for x and y scale factors : `scales = [(1,2),(2,1)]`
I want that the final image should be 300x300 and should contain the scaled version of the image. 
Thank you!!

Comment: This question does not make much sense, you want to stretch the image but you want to keep it the same size? Do you mean that you want to scale the image but crop down to the original size? Please post any code that you currently have and the expected outputs you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question and added what code I am using.

Comment: If you stretch an image, it will be larger. Do you want to stretch it and then crop part of the image that is the original size?

Comment: Yes but think of it like zooming out and then cropping it to 300x300. I want the 300x300 image to capture that the image was scaled and is different from original. Can something be done like padding then resizing or upsampling the image and then cropping it? This is for image augmentation.

Comment: Well, you can achieve this in two ways. One way is to set the *window size* of the display to your original image size, and display your image in that; but this only works for display purposes. Another way is to create a matrix of zeros (or whatever value), put a region of interest inside that is the same size as your scaled image, and place the scaled image inside the ROI. I'll post an answer with both solutions.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this just for display purposes, the easiest way is to use `cv2.imshow()` on your cropped image and use [`cv2.resizeWindow()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=cv2.resizewindow#resizewindow) to set the window size to the original image size.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]
scale = (0.6, 0.4) # define your scale
scaled_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=scale[0], fy=scale[1]) # scale image

cv2.namedWindow("Scaled image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) # create a resizeable window
cv2.imshow("Scaled image", scaled_img) # display the image in the window
cv2.resizeWindow("Scaled image", w, h) # resize the window
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Will display a scaled image inside the window where the window has the original image size. This will work even if you scale the image larger, by cropping the right side and top side of the image off (the image is anchored at the bottom left corner of the window). See the output window:

[image: Scaled Lena display]

If, however, you want this to be saved into another matrix, then you'll need to pad the image with whatever color you want outside of the image. The easiest way is to create a matrix with that color, but then create an ROI the size of your scaled image and place the scaled image within the ROI.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
scale = (0.6, 0.4) # define your scale
scaled_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=scale[0], fy=scale[1]) # scale image

sh, sw = scaled_img.shape[:2] # get h, w of scaled image
padded_scaled = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
padded_scaled[0:sh, 0:sw] = scaled_img

cv2.imshow("Scaled image", padded_scaled)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This will put the scaled image at `0,0` in the destination `padded_scaled`:

[image: Padded and scaled image]

If instead you want it displayed at the center, you can do some simple computations to get the center of the image, and then shift by half the width and height of the scaled image for the starting position.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
scale = (0.6, 0.4) # define your scale
scaled_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=scale[0], fy=scale[1]) # scale image

h, w = img.shape[:2] # get h, w of image
sh, sw = scaled_img.shape[:2] # get h, w of scaled image
center_y = int(h/2 - sh/2)
center_x = int(w/2 - sw/2)
padded_scaled = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8) # using img.shape to obtain #channels
padded_scaled[center_y:center_y+sh, center_x:center_x+sw] = scaled_img

cv2.imshow("Scaled image", padded_scaled)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This will place the scaled image in the center of the padded matrix:

[image: Scaled and centered image]

---

This will only work when images are scaled *smaller* than the original image, as you're placing a smaller image into a larger blank matrix. However, if you want to allow for larger scaling, then you'll need a crop at that point. You can just crop a region from the scaled image that is the same size as the original image. However, if the scale is larger than 1 in one dimension and less than 1 in another, you'll need to both crop *and* pad. I separated this into two sections of `if` statements: first create a result that is at most the size of the image by cropping if necessary, and *then* pad if it's smaller.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
scale_x, scale_y = 13, .3 # define your scale
h, w = img.shape[:2] # get h, w of image

if scale_x > 1 or scale_y > 1:

    scaled_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=scale_x, fy=scale_y, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR) # scale image
    sh, sw = scaled_img.shape[:2] # get h, w of scaled image
    center_y = int(sh/2 - h/2)
    center_x = int(sw/2 - w/2)
    cropped = scaled_img[center_y:center_y+h, center_x:center_x+w]

    result = cropped

elif scale_x > 0 or scale_y > 0:
    scaled_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=scale_x, fy=scale_y, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC) # scale image
    result = scaled_img

else: # scale_x or scale_y is negative
    print("Scales must be greater than 0; returning the original image.")
    result = img

if result.shape < img.shape: # one of the dimensions was scaled smaller, so need to pad
    sh, sw = result.shape[:2] # get h, w of cropped, scaled image
    center_y = int(h/2 - sh/2)
    center_x = int(w/2 - sw/2)
    padded_scaled = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    padded_scaled[center_y:center_y+sh, center_x:center_x+sw] = result
    result = padded_scaled

cv2.imshow("Scaled padded/cropped image", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

With a large stretch in one direction and a smaller scale in the other, this will result in an image displayed like this:

[image: Scaled, cropped, and padded image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! But unfortunately, I am getting errors like - could not broadcast input array from shape (xx,xx) into shape (xx,xx) when you try to fit in the scaled image into the padded image. Also, my input image is not 300x300. It is of some arbitrary size.

Comment: Can you actually post those shape numbers for an example? It's possible that you're not indexing correctly (maybe one of the images is one channel and the other is three channel?)

Comment: Yes sure. This is the actual error - could not broadcast input array from shape (1336,820) into shape (334,820). I do load the images in grayscale i.e add a 0 argument to argument read.

Comment: @Hooli let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146015/discussion-between-alexander-reynolds-and-hooli). I'll edit the post if it's necessary after we figure out that issue.

Comment: @Hooli I added code for the case where the image gets scaled larger in any direction. The method is to first crop a section, and if that crop is smaller, then pad. If this all works for you could you select my answer as a solution? Thanks!

Comment: It is perfect!!